# Does anyone know how can I analyse the UP 3 data on Windows 10?

Tags: jawbone

Copied from the old forum:

Hello,
  The app on the phone is good for analyzing the data from max 2-3 days.
I would like to have an access to the more detailed data on my computer.
Is there any way I can do that? Is there a tool for Windows 10, I could reach UP3 heart rate data? or sleep time?
Thank You in advance,
Agnieszka

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, Jawbone only provides mobile applications for iOS, Android, and Windows phones.

For retrieving UP user data on a non-mobile device, you have two options:

1. Download a CSV from the jawbone.com [Settings page](https://jawbone.com/user/settings#!accounts).
2. Use the [UP APIs](https://jawbone.com/up/developer/) to retrieve the data you want.